# How do I add extra space around the axis labels on a QwtPlot?

Tags: qt, qwt

I have a QwtPlot subclass that draws labels for the left and bottom axes and I would like to add some extra margins to these labels—specifically, between these labels and the tick marks’ numerical labels. Is there any built-in way to add such padding? (I’m using the [QwtPlainTextEngine](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plain_text_engine.html) to render the labels now, so I guess I could create my own subclass that adds extra space, but that would be much lower-level than I’d like.)

Answer (score 2):

See QwtAbstractScaleDraw::setSpacing()

Comment: See where? An answer is not complete if leaving it like this. You must at least add some more information to the answer or it'll probably be deleted

Comment: Come on, the question is about finding a specific API of a library and the answer names it explicitly. Feel free to remove my response, if this doesn't make sense for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer without helpful surrounding context the answer may be downvoted like you see

Comment: @Uwe I agree with you and in fact this was helpful to me. +1.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and solved like these methods.

**Method 1:**

We can give a margin with canvas like this

```
double margin = 30;
plot->plotLayout()->setCanvasMargin(margin, QwtPlot::yLeft);
plot->plotLayout()->setCanvasMargin(margin, QwtPlot::yRight);
```

Don't forget `#include <qwt_plot_layout.h>`

**Method 2:**

Using axis distance border distance. Here is the example:

```
double margin = 30;
plot->axisWidget(QwtPlot::xBottom)->setMinBorderDist(margin, margin);
```

Don't forget `#include <qwt_scale_widget.h>`

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: It looks like these methods adjust the amount of space between the axes and the edges of the widgets. I want to adjust the space between the axes’ text labels and the axes themselves.